# Problem that causes progress to come to a complete halt

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There are some problems that are minor and do not affect the overall operation at hand enough to stop it. For example, a broken radio is not a significant enough problem for driving a car. However, an empty gas tank is, and it needs to be resolved before the car can go.

What is an adjective to describe such a major problem or issue? I think I've heard a "gating issue" on a project I was involved in before, but a Google search didn't turn up much.

e.g. This is a _____ issue, so it needs to be resolved before we can make any progress.

Comment: Unhandled or fatal exception?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A term used in the software industry is [*showstopper*](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/showstopper.html):

> showstopper: n.
>
> A hardware or (especially) software bug that makes an implementation effectively unusable; one that absolutely has to be fixed before development can go on. Opposite in connotation from its original theatrical use, which refers to something stunningly *good*.

So you could say, "This is a showstopper, so it needs to be resolved before we can make any progress."

Comment: +1 for noting that the connotation is reversed from it's theatrical sense.

Comment: Showstopper is used in more industries than just software.

Comment: I'm not sure showstopper is quite right. That is more of a must have/must do feature/task for the final result to be valid rather than an issue that stops progress on other parts.

Comment: @JamesRyan: In the software world, hitting a showstopper frequently means your best developers are pulled from their assigned tasks and thrown onto the showstopper until a solution is found (and possibly until the solution has been coded and is in QA). So it does effectively stop progress on other fronts.

Comment: +1 "Showstopper" is the most common term. And its theatrical use actually means that some subset of the combined performance was so good it yanked the audience out their immersion in the performance i.e. they become aware they've seen something out of the ordinary and they pay attention to that and not the narrative being presented. Often causes spontaneous clapping, yelling, whistling etc which prevent the original production from continuing. In my theater experience, I've heard a truly bad performance described as a "showstopper" using sarcastic tone.

Answer (score 35):

Drop the word "issue" and say "This is a [**roadblock**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roadblock)." which means:

> something that stops progress

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 26):

This is a *blocking* issue:

> the action or process of obstructing movement, progress, or activity, in particular.
>   <sup>via [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+blocking)</sup>

Comment: An empty tank might be even be considered a _deadlock_: car can't go because tank is empty, but tank can't be filled because car won't go to gas station... — That word really is computer-specific, though.

Comment: The phrase "blocker" or "blocking issue" is used in many technical project-management-type situations, not just software projects.

Comment: In CS, *blocking* makes me think of blocking threads...

Comment: Where does the quote come from?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Google. I wasn't quite sure how to quote it with a link.

Comment: @MillieSmith: since Google doesn't say where they get their definitions from, the best you can do is cite Google itself. (The best guess from those in the know is that Google uses some version of the Oxford dictionary, but that hasn't ever been confirmed by Google itself.)

Comment: Or, the issue is *a blocker*.

Answer (score 12):

We call these a **Blocker**

> blocker: n.
>
> A task or problem that halts progress on a project.

Comment: Where does the quote come from?

Answer (score 10):

### "This is a [**critical**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/critical) issue."

> According to ODO
>
> 3.2 Having a decisive or crucial importance in the success, failure, or existence of something:
>
> *"temperature is a critical factor in successful fruit storage"*
> *"getting banks lending again was critical to any recovery"*
> *"time-critical tasks"*

For example:

**BSOD or Blue Screen of Death** is a serious problem seen on computers running Windows OS.

How To Geek's article "[Everything You Need To Know About the Blue Screen of Death](http://www.howtogeek.com/163452/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-blue-screen-of-death/)" (emphasis mine)

> BSODs appear when Microsoft Windows encounters a **critical** error it can’t recover from, requiring a reboot and possibly resulting in lost work.
>
> ...
>
> A blue screen occurs when Windows encounters a “STOP Error.” This **critical** failure causes Windows to crash and stop working. The only thing Windows can do is stop the computer and restart it.

Another example in the field of project management.

A [**critical task**](http://www.dictionaryofconstruction.com/definition/critical-task.html) is defined, by Dictionary of Construction, as

> A task or activity that lies on the critical path of the schedule, which if delayed will delay the completion of the project.

<sub><sup>***synonyms*** crucial, vital, essential, all-important, paramount, pre-eminent, fundamental, key, pivotal, decisive, climacteric, momentous</sup></sub>

Comment: Critical just means important. It doesn't indicate anything about the task's blocked state.

Comment: @MartinSmith In a slightly different context, it means what you said. But as per the definition 3.2 I've quoted, "critical" issues need to be resolved to allow progress.

Comment: Being critical is orthogonal to being blocked. It is entirely possible to have a task which is of crucial importance and is not blocked and not impeding progress.

Comment: Though actually I agree that it fits in the OP's example sentence as there the fact that the issue is blocked is implied.

Comment: @MartinSmith see my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try [prohibitive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prohibitive) (source - dictionary.com)

> serving or tending to prohibit or forbid something.
>
> sufficing to prevent the use, purchase, etc., of something

Also, [restrictive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/restrictive) (source - cambridge dictionary)

> limiting the freedom of someone or preventing something from growing.

Answer (score 6):

**impediment**

This is probably the most professional term fitting your definition.

According to Google, it means:

> a hindrance or obstruction in doing something.

Remember, however, to use it as a noun:

> The empty gas tank was an impediment.

And not an adjective:

> The empty gas tank was an impediment issue.

Comment: An impediment doesn't necessarily mean that progress has come to a complete halt though. A closed road necessitating a detour or a low gas tank could be impediments that require going out of your way, but they aren't blocking issues to a road trip in the same way that an engine fire would be.

Comment: It might be the most *formal*, but I don't think it is the most *professional*.

Answer (score 6):

Try **fatal**.
In computing: "In computing, a fatal error or fatal exception error is an error that causes a program to abort..."
-Wikipedia

> [Middle English, *fateful*, from Old French, from Latin *fātālis*, from *fātum*, *prophecy*, *doom*; see *fate*.]
>
> Synonyms: fatal, deadly, lethal, mortal
>   These adjectives apply to what causes or is likely to cause death. *Fatal* describes conditions, circumstances, or events that have already caused death or are virtually certain to do so in the future: *a fatal accident*; *a fatal illness*.
>
> Source: TheFreeDictionary

Comment: +1, that's the one I was scanning the page for. It should be pretty clear to any whether they've heard this usage or not. You don't recover from things that are fatal.

Answer (score 6):

A mechanical term might be something like a **wrench in the wheels/gears**.  Used to mean a small item that can cause the entire machine to grind to a halt.  It can of course be used metaphorically to relate to software or other showstopping problems as well.

Comment: "Spanner in the works"

Comment: @mccainz - That works too, though it's more of a British variant.  Many Americans wouldn't know what a "spanner" is.  Not sure about Canada, Australia, etc.

Comment: And, of course, this is related to the origin of the word "sabotage", meaning throwing a shoe ("sabot") into the works of some machine.

Comment: @HotLicks - True, but "sabotage" implies a deliberate action to muck things up, whereas a "wrench in the gears" could be accidental.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Could be, but generally isn't.  (Note that there's the reasonably common idiom "threw a wrench/spanner in the works", but I've never heard "dropped a wrench/spanner in/into the works".)

Comment: FWIW, I used Ngram to find "wrench in the works" and about 80% of the "hits" used something akin to "throw a wrench in the works", implying intentional sabotage.

Answer (score 4):

If your example is metaphorical, consider **deal-breaker**.

> any issue or factor that is significant enough to terminate a
>   negotiation, esp. in business or politics

Answer (score 3):

"We've **hit a wall**," is fairly common, usually when breaking the news to someone. It connotes a solid object that is high and wide and cannot be easily worked around or climbed over.

The "go" and "no-go" is used by some software teams. Modeled on the NASA launch sequence, wherein each station reports whether the systems it monitors are "go" for launch of "no-go" for launch. A single "no-go" in an arbitrary long sequence of checks halts the launch.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the British English corollary to Darrel Hoffman's answer.

> [**Spanner in the works**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+a+spanner+in+the+works) -to do something that prevents a plan or activity from succeeding

Answer (score 2):

Try "impassable" issue.

The definition, from Merriam-Webster, is "impossible to pass, cross, or travel over".

Answer (score 1):

There is really no commonly used adjective that meets your criteria.   You could say "running out of gas is a showstopper", but if you had a list of "issues", you would more likely list that as "sufficient gas" or similar.  if you then wanted to tag your issues you could use "non-negotiable", "required", "essential", etc. for those issues that would halt progress of not properly addressed.

Answer (score -3):

One of the senses of **[bottleneck](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bottleneck)** can be used in this context:

> A hindrance to progress or production. - [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bottleneck)

Comment: Bottlenecks actually allow work to progress, albeit rather slowly :)

Comment: Yeah, my first thought was **speed bump**, but I didn't think that addressed the question adequately.